# Pandas check if two values appear at the same time but in different order and store them

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe like

```
animal, small_animal, count
cat, dog, 1
cat, moo, 2
dog, cat, 3
moo, moo, 5
squirrel, moo, 1
moo, cat, 3
```

I would like to have stored together
`cat, dog` and `dog, cat`

So I need to check if something both appears but in different "orders" in the column and keep the third column. I thought of multiple different dataframes or a dictionary.
So far I did a `groupby` but I still can't work around other things.

Comment: and what do you want to do with the third column?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just want to keep the third column

Comment: Do you want to keep `moo moo`?

Comment: no i don't want to keep if no mutuals

Comment: How about two `moo moo` rows?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to compare the two columns joined in different order and filter out the same animals in two columns.

```py
m = (df['animal']+df['small_animal']).isin(df['small_animal']+df['animal'])

out = df[m & df['animal'].ne(df['small_animal'])]
```

```
print(out)

  animal small_animal  count
0    cat          dog      1
1    cat          moo      2
2    dog          cat      3
5    moo          cat      3
```

Comment: ok but i don't know if actually cat and dog are "mutuals"

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new column with the label

```py
df["label_col"] = df[["animal", "small_animal"]].apply(
      lambda x: "-".join(sorted(x)), axis=1
)

"""
Output
     animal small_animal count    label_col
0       cat          dog     1       cat-dog
1       cat          moo     2       cat-moo
2       dog          cat     3       cat-dog
3       moo          moo     5       moo-moo
4  squirrel          moo     1  moo-squirrel
5       moo          cat     3       cat-moo
"""
```

Then you can group by or do whatever you want with the ordered key `label_col`

Comment: ok but if I want to see if it is an inverted order then I will lose this info this way

Comment: how do you mean? there are ways to progress with keeping all the information of animal/small_animal. I see the output of the other answer seems to answer what you need.

Comment: Could you use a `set` here instead of a sorted list?

Answer (score 0):

### Records with different names which occur in reflected form

```py
names = ['animal', 'small_animal']

# include all pairs of animal names which occur in reflected form
is_reflected = pd.Index(df[names]).isin(pd.Index(df[reversed(names)]))

# exclude records where names are duplicated, sort of ('moo', 'moo') pairs
is_different = df.animal != df.small_animal

# extract counts for records with reflected and different names
df[is_reflected & is_different]['count']
```